# .jpg out of .cgi with java (IP Webcam)

Tags: java, cgi, processing, webcam

hy there, i hope i can explain my question:

i´ve an ip webcam and i want to read&save a .jpg file out of the path

> webacm-ip-adr:8084/snapshot.cgi

i´ve little java experience and would like to program it in processing to keep it simple:

i´ve found this link:

> https://www.java.net/node/702486

but its a slight overkill for me to understand it would be great if i can work with the 2 **processing examples**: *web/loadingimages*  and *net/httpClient*

or do i make an logic mistake and its not solveable this way ?

Comment: Have you tried what you are getting back just requesting that resource in a get request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use java lib "Apache Commons IO" to done it.

My Simple Code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://webacm-ip-adr:8084/snapshot.cgi");
InputStream input = url.openStream();
String jpg = "sample.jpg";
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(jpg);
IOUtils.copy(input, output);
```

Class "IOUtils" is a common tool for IO stream operation in commons-io jar.

Comment: thanks a lot !
this seems short and i try to make it running in processing (incl. library and so on)

Comment: I was about to comment that you don't even need commons-io for this, but apparently there's still not a standard Java mechanism for doing this. D'oh.

Comment: atm i also struggle a bit to include it into processing - but i give it a break and try it later - i just wanted to keep it as simple as possible, just a little sketch to grab an .jpg - but it seems way more complicated than i thought ^^